# Get strings between two keywords in text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file that has data for ~10000 samples in a repeating structure. The part of the structure I am interested in in is something like below and is repeated through out the file with a bunch of other text in-between these parts as well. I am interested in just getting the long string of characters.

My first idea was to just enumerate the lines an use an index but the character strings differ in length for each sample so they take up a diff number of lines resulting in that not working. My other thought was to use startswith() lines as 'start' and 'end' indexes then taking everything in the middle but I am having trouble with that, it just returns data for the first sample over and over.

Example Data:

```
...
...
SQ   SEQUENCE   707 AA;  82280 MW;  E9C1346D52BBF38F CRC64;
     SSQFSKEGDF PCQTEAGLSV IHTRQKSSQG NGYKPSFSDV SHFDFHQQLH SGEKSHTCDE
     CGKNFCYISA LRIHQRVHMG EKCYKCDVCG KEFSQSSHLQ THQRVHTGEK PFKCVECGKG
     FSRRSALNVH HKLHTGEKPY NCEECGKAFI HDSQLQEHQR IHTGEKPFKC DICGKSFCGR
     SRLNRHSMVH TAEKPFRCDT CDKSFRQRSA LNSHRMIHTG EKPYKCEECG KGFICRRDLY
     THHMVHTGEK PYNCKECGKS FRWASCLLKH QRVHSGEKPF KCEECGKGFY TNSQCYSHQR
     KCRECDMCFS VHVGEKP
//
...
...
```

Current code:

```
data = []

for idx,line in enumerate(lines):
    if line.startswith('ID') :
        prot_id = line.split()[1]
    if line.startswith('SQ'):
        start = idx+1
    if line.startswith('/'):
        end = idx    
    seq = lines[start:end]
    for i in range(len(seq)):
        seq[i] = seq[i].strip()
    seq = "".join(seq)
    seq = seq.replace(" ", "")
    data.append((prot_id, seq))
```

Comment: Can you please provide a little more details of your text file? What is `'ID'` in it?

Comment: Just a unique string of characters for each sample like this: `ID   ZN224_HUMAN `
So `prot_id = line.split()[1]` just give me the unique IDs.

Comment: For one thing, you are creating a seq (`lines[start:end]`) for every line read instead of only when the `end` is assigned to. I don't know why you are just getting the same over and over. The data list is getting appended to for every line in `lines` and I think you only want it appended to when `end` is assigned to.

Answer (score 0):

An approach to consider (where data is a dictionary, not a list as in your code) You could use a list, but I think a dictionary would serve as a better data structure here.

```
data = dict() # if using data as a dictiomnary
#data = []    # if using data as a list
start = False
seq = ''

with open(my_file, 'r') as f:

    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('ID') :
            prot_id = line.split()[1]
        elif line.startswith('SQ'):
            start = True
        elif line.startswith('//'):
            data[prot_id] = seq          # if data defined as a dictionary
            #data.append([prot_id, seq]) # if data defined as a list
            seq = ''
            start = False
        elif start == True:
            seq += line.strip().replace(" ", "")
```